# install oracle java 8 with sources on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

i used `ppa:webupd8team/java` ppa to get java 8 on ubuntu. full instructions [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html). and everything works properly but when i browse sources in intellij, some sources are missing, for example for `javax.crypto` package. Intellij, (in project structure -> SDKs -> sourcepath) reports only 2 src files detected: `src.zip` and `javafx-src.zip`, both under `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`.

so the question is: can i somehow install all the sources automatically from some ppa or do i have to manually download all the necessary zips myself?

Comment: I have the same thing in my installation, but java works properly on my system. Also `src.zip` is the full source code for java so I don't know what other sources you may be referring to

Comment: it works properly for me too. the problem is missing some sources. i go to the [oracle download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) choose linux64 tar.gz, download, inside this archive there is `src.zip` and inside that zip there is no javax.crypto package